# Put simulation nodes at specific position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like put node at specific position with simulation forceX/Y, I expected strength 0 means no any strength to X and Y, then nodes should be put at the position defined by nodes.

What's proper way to put nodes at specific position with simulation?

```js
drag_nodes()

function add_grids(g,width,height) {
    var m = 10
    var n = 10
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,m])
        .range([0, width])
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,n])
        .range([0,height])

    var xaxis = g.append('g')
        .attr('class','xaxis')
        .call(d3.axisTop(xScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSizeOuter(0)
              .tickSize(0)
              //.tickValues([])
             )
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    
    var yaxis = g.append('g')
        .attr('class','yaxis')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null)//i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSizeOuter(0)
              .tickSize(0)
              //.tickValues([])
             )
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

    g.selectAll("g.yaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
    //.attr("stroke-dasharray","4") // make it dashed;;

    g.selectAll("g.xaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", height)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
}

function drag_nodes() {
    var data = {
        nodes: [{
            name: "A",
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        }, {
            name: "B",
            x: 100,
            y: 400
        }, {
            name: "C",
            x: 400,
            y: 400
        }, {
            name: "D",
            x: 400,
            y: 100
        }],
        links: [{
            source: 'A',
            target: 'B'
        }, {
            source: 'B',
            target: 'C'
        }, {
            source: 'C',
            target: 'D'
        }, ]
    };
    
    var width = 500
    var height = 500
    
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style('border','2px solid red')

    add_grids(svg,width,height)

    var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);

    function dragstarted(event,d) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }
    function dragged(event,d) {
        d.fx = event.x;
        d.fy = event.y;
    }
    function dragended(event,d) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }
  
    var link = svg.selectAll("link")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    var node = svg.selectAll("node")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y
        })
        .attr("r", 15)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colors(i);
        })
        .call(drag);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.name; }))
        .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(0))
        .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(0))//.strength(1))
        .alpha(1).restart();
    
    simulation.nodes(data.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(data.links);

    function ticked() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        }       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said...

> I expected strength 0 means no any strength to X and Y, then nodes should be put at the position defined by nodes.

But it's the opposite: the `link` force pulls the nodes together, hence the need of `forceX` and `forceY` with a high strength.

You can see this if you remove the links:

```js
drag_nodes()

function add_grids(g,width,height) {
    var m = 10
    var n = 10
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,m])
        .range([0, width])
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,n])
        .range([0,height])

    var xaxis = g.append('g')
        .attr('class','xaxis')
        .call(d3.axisTop(xScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSizeOuter(0)
              .tickSize(0)
              //.tickValues([])
             )
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    
    var yaxis = g.append('g')
        .attr('class','yaxis')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null)//i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSizeOuter(0)
              .tickSize(0)
              //.tickValues([])
             )
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

    g.selectAll("g.yaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
    //.attr("stroke-dasharray","4") // make it dashed;;

    g.selectAll("g.xaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", height)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
}

function drag_nodes() {
    var data = {
        nodes: [{
            name: "A",
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        }, {
            name: "B",
            x: 100,
            y: 400
        }, {
            name: "C",
            x: 400,
            y: 400
        }, {
            name: "D",
            x: 400,
            y: 100
        }],
        links: [{
            source: 'A',
            target: 'B'
        }, {
            source: 'B',
            target: 'C'
        }, {
            source: 'C',
            target: 'D'
        }, ]
    };
    
    var width = 500
    var height = 500
    
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style('border','2px solid red')

    add_grids(svg,width,height)

    var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);

    function dragstarted(event,d) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }
    function dragged(event,d) {
        d.fx = event.x;
        d.fy = event.y;
    }
    function dragended(event,d) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }
  
    var link = svg.selectAll("link")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    var node = svg.selectAll("node")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y
        })
        .attr("r", 15)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colors(i);
        })
        .call(drag);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(0))
        .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(0))//.strength(1))
        .alpha(1).restart();
    
    simulation.nodes(data.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    function ticked() {

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        }       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

But in that case you simply don't need a simulation.

Therefore, to counteract the pulling force of the links, you need to set a higher strength to the positioning forces:

```js
drag_nodes()

function add_grids(g, width, height) {
  var m = 10
  var n = 10

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, m])
    .range([0, width])

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n])
    .range([0, height])

  var xaxis = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .call(d3.axisTop(xScale)
      .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
      .tickSize(0)
      //.tickValues([])
    )
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

  var yaxis = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'yaxis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
      .tickSize(0)
      //.tickValues([])
    )
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

  g.selectAll("g.yaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
  //.attr("stroke-dasharray","4") // make it dashed;;

  g.selectAll("g.xaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", height)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
}

function drag_nodes() {
  var data = {
    nodes: [{
      name: "A",
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    }, {
      name: "B",
      x: 100,
      y: 400
    }, {
      name: "C",
      x: 400,
      y: 400
    }, {
      name: "D",
      x: 400,
      y: 100
    }],
    links: [{
      source: 'A',
      target: 'B'
    }, {
      source: 'B',
      target: 'C'
    }, {
      source: 'C',
      target: 'D'
    }, ]
  };

  var width = 500
  var height = 500

  var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style('border', '2px solid red')

  add_grids(svg, width, height)

  var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended);

  function dragstarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
  }

  function dragended(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  var link = svg.selectAll("link")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black");

  var node = svg.selectAll("node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(drag);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(5))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(5)) //.strength(1))
    .alpha(1).restart();

  simulation.nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);

  function ticked() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, in that very specific case, the links pushing force can be avoided setting a precise link distance, which is `300`:

```js
drag_nodes()

function add_grids(g, width, height) {
  var m = 10
  var n = 10

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, m])
    .range([0, width])

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n])
    .range([0, height])

  var xaxis = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .call(d3.axisTop(xScale)
      .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
      .tickSize(0)
      //.tickValues([])
    )
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

  var yaxis = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'yaxis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
      .tickSize(0)
      //.tickValues([])
    )
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

  g.selectAll("g.yaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
  //.attr("stroke-dasharray","4") // make it dashed;;

  g.selectAll("g.xaxis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "gridline")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", height)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "#9ca5aecf") // line color
}

function drag_nodes() {
  var data = {
    nodes: [{
      name: "A",
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    }, {
      name: "B",
      x: 100,
      y: 400
    }, {
      name: "C",
      x: 400,
      y: 400
    }, {
      name: "D",
      x: 400,
      y: 100
    }],
    links: [{
      source: 'A',
      target: 'B'
    }, {
      source: 'B',
      target: 'C'
    }, {
      source: 'C',
      target: 'D'
    }, ]
  };

  var width = 500
  var height = 500

  var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style('border', '2px solid red')

  add_grids(svg, width, height)

  var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended);

  function dragstarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
  }

  function dragended(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.1);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  var link = svg.selectAll("link")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black");

  var node = svg.selectAll("node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(drag);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }).distance(300))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(0))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(0)) //.strength(1))
    .alpha(1).restart();

  simulation.nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);

  function ticked() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```